# Python: add a list to vector attribute table

Tags: python, vector, attribute-table

I have a raster from which I have extracted the zonal statistics using a vector grid (shapefile). As a result, I have now a list containing the mean values extracted from each element of the grid.
However, unlike when running zonal statistics in QGIS, the list is not present (as a new column) in the attribute table of the shapefile.

How can I add such a list to the attribute table of the shapefile?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Check this tutorial [QGIS Tutorials and Tips | Running Processing Algorithms via Python (QGIS3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_algorithms_pyqgis.html).

Comment: try in the Python Console `params = {'INPUT_RASTER': rlayer.name(), 'RASTER_BAND': 1, 'INPUT_VECTOR': vlayer.name(), 'COLUMN_PREFIX': prefix+'_', 'STATS': 2}` and then `processing.run("qgis:zonalstatistics", params)`

Comment: Thanks Taras. However, I was hoping to do this with a stand alone python script, not in QGIS. Sorry if I wasn't clear.